# Clear Jasmine fixture after each test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I have a Rails 4 app and am using the jasmine but can't seem to find an example about how to run a global afterEach on my test suite. I want `#jasmine_content` emptied after each test is run so that there is no conflicts. I can add a `afterEach` call to each of my test files, but it would be nice to have it run for by default and never have to call it. Does anyone know how to do this? I was thinking you may be able to add a support file that always gets run, but haven't been able to do this yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the jasmine gem will load any files in `<spec_dir>/helpers` before loading any of your tests. You can put a `specHelper.js` in there, similar to how you would for rspec, and just add an `afterEach` or `beforeEach` in there, but not in a `describe` and it will affect all specs in your suite.